# element Ui: Carousel - How to set current slide

Tags: carousel, vuejs2, vue.js

I have hard time to figure out how to use the carousel and more specifically how to set the current slide.

Here is the doc [of the component](http://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs#/en-US/component/carousel#carousel-methods)

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wd1a1toh/)

```
<div id="app">

 <button v-on:click="setActiveItem('first')">Go First</button>
 <button v-on:click="setActiveItem('second')">Go Second</button>

 <template>
   <el-carousel indicator-position="none" autoplay='false'>
       <el-carousel-item name ='first'>
           <h3>First</h3>
       </el-carousel-item>
       <el-carousel-item name ='second'>
         <h3>Second</h3>
       </el-carousel-item>
  </el-carousel>
</template>
```

I think it should be related to the fact the method setActiveItem is linked to the component but I don't know how to call it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `setActiveItem` as well for the vue instance whcih will access `this.$refs.carousel.setActiveItem` to change current slide, like following:

```
var Main = {
    methods: {
      setActiveItem(index) {
        this.$refs.carousel.setActiveItem(index);
      }
    }
  }
```

see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wd1a1toh/1/).